# authorized .net payment gateway in ios createTransactionRequest

Tags: ios, swift, authorize.net

I am working with authorized .net payement gateway in ios
How to create Transaction Request?

I have integrate SDK from here.
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios

Token is getting successfully.

But I can't understand how to make transaction with passing amount and item. (I mean How to make payment?) Any request URL or method available for this?

Please give me guideline here.

Answer (score 1):

After obtaining the token, your server constructs a transaction request using the Authorize.Net API, placing the token in the opaqueData element.

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios#using-the-accept-payment-token-to-create-a-transaction-request

Comment: @Miteshjadav  Correct.